# Using javascript intellisense in visual studio code while using .script

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Because of .js security issue, I'm using .script extension instead of .js.

Is it possible to use javascript intellisense in visual studio code while using .script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and type <kbd>CTRL/Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>, then "Change language mode"

You should be able to chose "Javascript", forcing VSCode to apply Javascript completion to your current file.